# The graph associated with transportation tableau is a spanning tree

Tags: linear-programming, optimal-transport

The transportation problem in linear programming is solved by a kind of simplex method in which we use a [transportation tableau](https://www.utdallas.edu/~scniu/OPRE-6201/documents/TP1-Formulation.pdf) which corresponds to a basic solution.  (See page 5 of the given link)

If we put a dot in each cell of the tableau and connect the dots which correspond to a similar row (or a similar column), a graph is made which corresponds to that basis.

How can we show that :

(a) This graph is connected.

(b) For each row and each column of the transportation tableau, there is a vertex in the graph. (This graph associated with a basis, is spanning)